# Can't get pid after executing command

Tags: linux, bash

I need to execute `node` and `firefox` in that order. The node process needs to remain in the background until I close firefox manually.

I've tried this command:

`node & nodePID=$! && firefox && pkill $nodePID`

but `$nodePID` seems to return pid of firefox instead of node. How would I fix this?

*Note that I can't just `pkill node` since I might have different node processes running at the same time.*

Comment: Can't reproduce on *GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)*. Which version of bash is this?

Comment: @oguzismail GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Okay. Normally `node &` would print a pid number to the terminal, can you confirm when you run `node & pid=$! && firefox && echo $pid` prints to different pids?

Comment: It prints pid once, but it's not the node pid.

Comment: Weird. But it's hard to say what's going on without being able to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `kill $nodePID` instead of `pkill ...`.

Also you want NOT to chain the commands with '&&'. For example, if firefox fail to launch, you still probably want to cleanup the node process. The assignment (nodePID=...) will never fail.

```
node &
nodePID=$!
firefox
kill $nodePID
```